# Is this FastMM4 Invalid Pointer Exception a bug in FastMM for Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, fastmm

In Delphi 5, with FastMM active, the call to `FreeMem` in the following *minimum-reproducible code* triggers an **Invalid Pointer Exception**:

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  FastMM4,
  SysUtils,
  Windows;

procedure Main;
var
    token: THandle;
    returnLength: Cardinal;
    p: Pointer;
begin
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, {out}token);

    //Get the size of the buffer required.
    //It's normally going to be 38 bytes. We'll use 16KB to eliminate the possibility of buffer overrun
//  Windows.GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, nil, 0, {var}returnLength);
    p := GetMemory(16384); //GetMemory(returnLength);

    Windows.GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, p, 1024, {var}returnLength);

    FreeMem({var}p); //FreeMem is the documented way to free memory allocated with GetMemory.
//  FreeMemory(p); //FreeMemory is the C++ compatible version of FreeMem.
end;

begin
    Main;
end.
```

The call to **`FreeMme`** fails with an `EInvalidPointerException`:

```
FreeMem({var}p); //error
```

The error will stop happening if:

- i stop using FastMM4
- i stop calling `GetTokenInformation`
- i call `FreeMemory` *(rather than `FreeMem`)*

I've reproduced the error on a fresh install of Delphi 5 on a freshly installed Windows 7 machine. FastMM4 v4.992.

- The error does not happen in Delphi 7
- The error does not happen in Delphi XE6

It's only:

- Delphi 5
- when using FastMM4

### Workaround

If it is a bug in FastMM4, i can workaround it. Rather than calling:

- GetMemory
- FreeMem

I can manually allocate the buffer another way:

- SetLength(buffer, cb)
- SetLength(buffer, 0)

If it's not a bug in FastMM4, i'd like to fix the above code.

### Using FreeMemory, rather than FreeMem, doesn't trigger the error

I was under the impression that FastMM takes over memory management, which is why i was surprised to discover:

- `FreeMem({var}p);`  *failed*
- `FreeMemory(p);` *works*

Internally, **FreeMem** is implemented as a call to the memory manager. In this case the memory manager (FastMM) returns non-zero, causing the call to `reInvalidPtr`:

**System.pas**

```
procedure _FreeMem;
asm
        TEST    EAX,EAX
        JE      @@1
        CALL    MemoryManager.FreeMem
        OR      EAX,EAX
        JNE     @@2
@@1:    RET
@@2:    MOV     AL,reInvalidPtr
        JMP     Error
end;
```

and the implementation of **MemoryManager.FreeMem** ends up being:

**FastMM4.pas**

```
function FastFreeMem(APointer: Pointer);
```

### FreeMem takes a var pointer, FreeMemory takes a pointer

The implementation of **FreeMemory** is:

**System.pas**:

```
function FreeMemory(P: Pointer): Integer; cdecl;
begin
  if P = nil then
    Result := 0
  else
    Result := SysFreeMem(P);
end;
```

And **SysFreeMem** is implemented in:

**GetMem.inc**:

```
function SysFreeMem(p: Pointer): Integer;
// Deallocate memory block.
label
  abort;
var
  u, n : PUsed;
  f : PFree;
  prevSize, nextSize, size : Integer;
begin
  heapErrorCode := cHeapOk;

  if not initialized and not InitAllocator then begin
    heapErrorCode := cCantInit;
    result := cCantInit;
    exit;
  end;

  try
    if IsMultiThread then EnterCriticalSection(heapLock);

    u := p;
    u := PUsed(PChar(u) - sizeof(TUsed)); { inv: u = address of allocated block being freed }
    size := u.sizeFlags;
    { inv: size = SET(block size) + [block flags] }

    { validate that the interpretation of this block as a used block is correct }
    if (size and cThisUsedFlag) = 0 then begin
      heapErrorCode := cBadUsedBlock;
      goto abort;
    end;

    { inv: the memory block addressed by 'u' and 'p' is an allocated block }

    Dec(AllocMemCount);
    Dec(AllocMemSize,size and not cFlags - sizeof(TUsed));

    if (size and cPrevFreeFlag) <> 0 then begin
      { previous block is free, coalesce }
      prevSize := PFree(PChar(u)-sizeof(TFree)).size;
      if (prevSize < sizeof(TFree)) or ((prevSize and cFlags) <> 0) then begin
        heapErrorCode := cBadPrevBlock;
        goto abort;
      end;

      f := PFree(PChar(u) - prevSize);
      if f^.size <> prevSize then begin
        heapErrorCode := cBadPrevBlock;
        goto abort;
      end;

      inc(size, prevSize);
      u := PUsed(f);
      DeleteFree(f);
    end;

    size := size and not cFlags;
    { inv: size = block size }

    n := PUsed(PChar(u) + size);
    { inv: n = block following the block to free }

    if PChar(n) = curAlloc then begin
      { inv: u = last block allocated }
      dec(curAlloc, size);
      inc(remBytes, size);
      if remBytes > cDecommitMin then
        FreeCurAlloc;
      result := cHeapOk;
      exit;
    end;

    if (n.sizeFlags and cThisUsedFlag) <> 0 then begin
      { inv: n is a used block }
      if (n.sizeFlags and not cFlags) < sizeof(TUsed) then begin
        heapErrorCode := cBadNextBlock;
        goto abort;
      end;
      n.sizeFlags := n.sizeFlags or cPrevFreeFlag
    end else begin
      { inv: block u & n are both free; coalesce }
      f := PFree(n);
      if (f.next = nil) or (f.prev = nil) or (f.size < sizeof(TFree)) then begin
        heapErrorCode := cBadNextBlock;
        goto abort;
      end;
      nextSize := f.size;
      inc(size, nextSize);
      DeleteFree(f);
      { inv: last block (which was free) is not on free list }
    end;

    InsertFree(u, size);
abort:
    result := heapErrorCode;
  finally
    if IsMultiThread then LeaveCriticalSection(heapLock);
  end;
end;
```

So it makes that sense that **FreeMemory** doesn't trigger the error; **FreeMemory** is not taken over by the memory manager.

I guess that is why [**FreeMemory** is not the documented counterpart to **GetMemory**:](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_GetMemory.html)

[image]

Comment: Did you compare declaration of `GetTokenInformation` in Delphi 5 and Delphi 7? Maybe is something wrong with it.

Comment: @zed I did; they're identical, and identically correct. And there's no issue with structure alignment here; as there are no structures.

Comment: I don't know where you get *FreeMem is the documented way to free memory allocated with GetMemory.*, because it's not. [*To dispose of the buffer, use FreeMemory.*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.GetMemory) If you allocate with `GetMemory`, free it with `FreeMemory`. If you allocate with `GetMem`, free it with `FreeMem`.

Comment: @KenWhite I got it from the documentation (added link, and archive, and screenshot)

Comment: @IanBoyd This is an error in old documentation. [Here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_FreeMemory.html) is they say *GetMemory allocates a block on the heap. To dispose of the buffer, use FreeMemory.*

Comment: @zed That would explain it then. In Delphi 5 **GetMemory** was a hard-coded internal implementation that lived in a `.inc` file. As of Delphi 7, **GetMemory** and **FreeMemory** was re-designed to call the MemoryManager, rather than an internal hard-coded memory manager.

Comment: @zed Put all that in the form of an answer, and you'll have yourself an *Accept* after i get back from lunch.

Comment: I think that is @KenWhite 's answer, not mine.

Comment: I must admit I was wondering why you weren't calling GetMem

Comment: @zed You pointed out the error, rather than critiquing the question. Your comment *led* to me figuring out the solution. You deserve the most credit. Otherwise i'll write up an answer and nobody gets any rep!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan **GetMem** is difficult to use when you have want to assign the newly allocated pointer to a property, or pass it to a method. Don't forget that minimal-reproducible code examples are immune from any such criticisms.

Comment: The need to use try/finally to protect against leaks means that you don't actually write the sort of code you are describing. You can't pass the return value of GetMemory to GetTokenInformation because you need to inject a try. So that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Again, don't confuse a minimal-complete code example for reality.

Comment: Critiquing the question has nothing to do with being able to comment and provide a correct answer. Reputation is earned for the latter.

Comment: Reality? Reality is writing try immediately after the memory is allocated, and so not passing function return value directly it to a function.

Comment: Usually the only reason to write `try` immediately after a memory allocation is to `finally` free it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FreeMem` is not the documented way to free memory allocated with `GetMemory` - that's apparently an error in the old documentation that has since been corrected.  From the [documentation for System.GetMemory](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.GetMemory) (**emphasis** added):

> `GetMemory` allocates a memory block.
>
> `GetMemory` allocates a block of the given Size on the heap, and returns the address of this memory. The bytes of the allocated buffer are not set to zero. **To dispose of the buffer, use `FreeMemory`.** If there is not enough memory available to allocate the block, an `EOutOfMemory` exception is raised.

If you allocate the memory with `GetMem`, use `FreeMem`. If the allocation is done with `GetMemory`, use `FreeMemory`.

Comment: It should be noted that in Delphi 5, neither **GetMemory** nor **FreeMemory** use the registered [**MemoryManager**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.GetMemoryManager). If you wanted to use a custom memory manager (e.g. FastMM), then any calls to **GetMemory** or **FreeMemory** bypass the registered memory manager. By Delphi 7 this had changed, and both `GetMem`/`FreeMem` and `GetMemory`/`FreeMemory` use the installed memory manager. But if you are still on Delphi 5, you will have to avoid `GetMemory`/`FreeMemory`.